# Multiple Authentication Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to figure out a problem I currently have. I have a software platform where restaurant owners can make and publish their own mobile apps. Menu access, reservation control, etc etc. I am using Firebase as my backend.

For each restaurant app I make, requires a customer login. The problem is that the customer can download another app from my restaurant client and has the ability to log in with the same credentials because I am using the same Firebase project for multiple apps, under the same company.

This is not what I want.. can I make multiple instances of Firebase Authentication? Or when the user registers, do I hardcode the username and password into the database, and check that, upon registration and signing in? If I did that, I would lose the power of third party log ins.

Please let me know of any ideas you guys might have..

Thanks!
Jorge

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Auth can't have multiple instances per project.  You would need to create multiple projects to in order to get more instances.

However, what you're talking about could be called "multi-tenancy", where you have multiple organizations each sandboxed from each other in a single project.  For that, you will need to adopt [Google Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs) and work with it using the Firebase APIs as described by the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-authentication).

Comment: fyi: there is now also [Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#identity-platform) which is a nice click-through integration from Firebase Authentication to the Cloud Identity platform.